# (To take / Taking) the subway often makes me feel like I'm trapped in an aquarium

Tags: grammar

A. To take the subway often makes me feel like I'm trapped in an aquarium. 
B. Taking the subway often makes me feel like I'm trapped in an aquarium.

I want to know which sentence is correct.
Some say 'To take' can't be the answer but some say the two words are interchangeable each other in this sentence.

What is the answer in this sentence?

Sometimes It is very difficult for us (non native speaker) to understand the difference between infinitive form and gerund form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is correct. The first could/should be written in the subjunctive as follows:

> To take the subway would make me feel trapped as (if I was) in an aquarium

The second is describing a regular activity (i.e. it is describing an feeling that the narrator actually feels) whereas the first conveys something a little more conditional/theoretical (*"if I were to do X, then Y would follow..."*)